# R version 3.2.4 "very secure dishes" on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, how can I open a file given by an user in a function?

Tags: r, function, loops

I am quite new in stackexchange and in R. 
I am following a course on R, and as an assignment I have a series of more than 300 files.  I have to create a function which takes a certain nb of those files as argument in a vector (here id) : `myfunction<-function(directory, variable, id=1:332)`. The files are in .csv format and are called 001.csv until 332.csv.

My question is how to open a given file where the nb of the file is the number in id. 
For instance, if I call `myfunction(directory, variable, 1)`, I would like to open the first file (001.csv), etc. If I call `myfunction(directory, variable, 1:4)`, I would like the program to open the 4 first files. 
Here is an attempt, which doesn't work:

```
myfunction<-function(directory, variable, id=1:332)
{
    for(i in id)
    {
        data<-read.csv("i.csv")
    } 
    #data<-read.csv("")
}
```

I precise that this question is the first step of a function that I have to write and not the whole assignment ;) !

Answer (score 1):

use `paste0()`. Something like

```
data <- read.csv(paste0(directory, "/", i, ".csv"))
```

Comment: yes it works, thanks a lot ! I actually embedded this into lot of if tests to take any name of file, adding some 0 for the files which are named with a number < 100; and it works fine!